# Using Recursion to make sequences of a word

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, sequence

I was given a homework assignment to find all possible sequences of a given word. eg. if `word = 'abc'`, the below code would return `['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'acb', 'b', 'ba', 'bac', 'bc', 'bca', 'c', 'ca', 'cab', 'cb', 'cba']`.

However, this feels inefficient. I'm just starting to learn recursion, so I'm not sure if there is a better or more efficient way to produce these sequences?

edit:
I think it's necessary to add a couple things as I kept working and reading the material

- Duplicates are fine, those are sorted out in a separate function
- Each value is unique, so sequence 'aab' should produce two 'aa' sequences

---

```
def gen_all_strings(word):
    if len(word) == 1:
        return list(word)
    else:
        main_list = list()
        for idx in range(len(word)):
            cur_val = word[idx]
            rest = gen_all_strings(word[:idx] + word[idx+1:])
            main_list.append(cur_val)
            for seq in rest:
                main_list.append(cur_val + seq)
        return main_list
```

Comment: If you're only looking for efficiency, python has an optimized [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library that has built-in cobination/permutation functions

Answer (score 0):

Itertools and list comprehensions are good for breaking stuff down like this.

```
import itertools

["".join(x) for y in range(1, len(word) + 1) for x in itertools.permutations(word, y)]
```